# How to expose amqps rabbitmq protocol in k8s environment externally?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I was wondering -
When setting rabbitmq nodes to use a TLS connection (as seen here https://github.com/artooro/rabbitmq-kubernetes-ha/blob/master/configmap.yaml), as I understand, I need to create a certificate that matches the hostname, wildcard can be used - https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering-ssl.html.

As cluster dns is internal, I guess I should create a certificate with a common name such as - ‘*.rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local’.

When I’m exposing the service, I'm supposed to create either a NodePort service or a LoadBalancer service - with a totally different hostname (it should route internally).

My question is - how will the amqps connection work? Won't it present me with one of the node’s certificates - which will not match the load balancer’s dns?

What's the correct way to expose the amqps protocol?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking at it, it doesn't matter - this is not a "standard" https connection.

The client needs to specify the correct common name and that's enough for the connection to work.